# Создание инсталлятора с VS библиотеками

Tags: c++

Написал небольшое приложение на С++(VS2017) и сделал инсталлятор куда его собственно и положил, но при переносе на другой компьютер, на котором не установлены библиотеки VS2017, получил ошибки при загрузке библиотек в рантайме. В связи с этим вопрос: какие необходимо брать с собой библиотеки в инсталлятор, чтобы на других компьютерах приложение успешно заработало, либо может есть готовые паки для этого?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads, необходимые вам инсталляторы лучше включить в свой инсталлятор как опцию ("Установить файлы VC2017") и по этой опции запускать сам инсталлер от майкрософта

Comment: А можно ли это как-нибудь с CPack сконфигурировать? Просто я в нем инсталлятор собираю...

Comment: с CPack не работал

Comment: Добавьте в CMake `include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)`, это скопирует необходимые dll туда же, куда вы делаете `install` Вашего приложения, оттуда потом забирайте с помощью CPack в один пакет. Это не лучший метод, т.к. таскать с собой библиотеки студии в принципе не очень верно, но работать будет. По уму нужно делать нормальный установщик через какой-нибудь wix и включать туда то, что Вам привели в первом комментарии.